# Drupal 7 displays IP address in internal links instead of URL

Tags: uri

The website I am developing with Drupal 7.17 continues to show the IP address in the links.
I have configured the URL to point toward the site this works  though the internal links display the IP address.

I have modified the `$base_url` in settings.php but this does not affect it. I have also cleared the caches in my Drupal install as well as Mysql database cache. The hosts file is set to point to the URL but still it's not displaying the the URL in the links.

The website and links work on the local computer development environment.

Comment: Make a raw php file and see what $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] contains when you open that page in a FQDN.

Comment: Hello Yes I made the php file the file just gave the server IP address. I am considering that this may be problem with the hosts file setup. As this not a problem on my local machine

Comment: Solved the problem it was a database bug/problem.It was continuing to store IP address even when I changed hosts. I used a backup of the database in the end.